# Awk: printing the average of each line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file titled "marks" with lines refering to a student's name, surname and 4 marks of the classes he took this semester for each line like this:

```
John McJohn 56 68 31 99
Ronald McDonald 89 89 60 75
Boaty McBoatface 50 50 50 50
```

I try to create an awk script that prints each line with the average mark for each line (aka each student) and the number of the line he is.

f.e.

```
Student 1, John McJohn, 63,5
Student 2, Ronald McDonald, 78.25
```

and so on and so on.

What I came up with is the following:

```
{
    for(i=0; i<FNR; i++)
    {
        avg=($3+$4+$5+$6)/4;
        printf("Student %d, %s %s, %.2f\n", i, $1, $2, avg);
    }
}
```

But the output of this is a mess that seems like a cartesian product:

[image]

I'm suspecting there is something wrong with the `i<FNR` expression that boggles the lines for each loop.

How it should've been?

Comment: I think you mean `%.2f`, not with the $ sign

Comment: You do not have to loop. awk does the looping over each line for you. Something like this is enough: `awk '{print "Student " NR ",", $1 $2 "," , ($3+$4+$5+$6)/4}' yourfile`.

Comment: @user2314737 it's a typo, I'm editing it out right now.

Comment: @LarsFischer that seems to do it just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the students' names are unique in the file you don't need the `for` loop

```
avg=($3+$4+$5+$6)/4;
printf("Student %d, %s %s, %.2f\n", NR, $1, $2, avg);
```

Where you could use a `for` loop is for computing the sum (this can be convenient in case you have more than 4 fields to add):

```
for (i=3;i<7;i++) avg+=$i;
avg=avg/4;
printf("Student %d, %s %s, %.2f\n", NR, $1, $2, avg)}
```